# Parse object save in PhoneGap/Cordova on Android saving successfully but triggering error callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, error-handling, parse-platform

I have followed the JavaScript SDK example like so:

I can see that my data is being saved in Parse via the Data Browser but the error callback is being triggered.

```
    var Senior = Parse.Object.extend('Senior'),
                senior = new Senior();
            senior.save({
                telNumber: $('#seniorTel').val(),
                avatarImage: $('#imgData').val()
            }, {
                success: function(senior) {
                    // The object was saved successfully.
                    alert('New object created with objectId: ' + senior.id);
                },
                error: function(senior, error) {
                    // The save failed.
                    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                    alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
                }
            });
```

I am using Parse as the JavaScript framework, Zepto as the DOM lib & Cordova 2.9 for the app.

Comment: Any errors in LogCat. Which alert shows **success or error**.

Comment: only what i alert out, error code is -1